# How to run android testapp using robotium on android device(commercial phone)

Tags: android, automation, using, robotium

I execute several android testapps on an emulator, but I am really confused how to run testapp on a commercial phone. If any detailed steps mentioned in any of the site please publish the links ..... Really need it. Thanks in advance. Congrats to Renas...:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb commands to run your app and tests on a phone. [This page](http://controlingquality.blogspot.com/2011/02/test-android-apk-file-with-robotium.html) gives you proper instructions, at the bottom of the page.